# Terraform 12 unable to deploy beanstalk healthreporting settings

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, terraform

I included healthreporting on my terraform deployment however I'm getting this error

**ERROR**

```
Error: Unsupported argument

  on ../mods/environment/environment.tf line 210, in resource "aws_elastic_beanstalk_environment" "environment":
 210:   setting = {

An argument named "setting" is not expected here. Did you mean to define a
block of type "setting"?
```

I am using this json file on the template folder

**hc.tpl file = located in ../mods/environment/hc folder**

```
{
  "CloudWatchMetrics": {
    "Environment": {
      "ApplicationRequests2xx": 60,
      "ApplicationRequests5xx": 60,
      "ApplicationRequests4xx": 60
  },
  "Instance": {
      "ApplicationRequestsTotal": 60
    }
  },
  "Version": 1
}
```

**My Terraform code deployment *(I removed some blocks to lessen your reading)***

```
data "template_file" "hc" {
  template = "${file("../mods/environment/hc/hc.tpl")}"
}

resource "aws_elastic_beanstalk_environment" "pogi" {
  name                    = "pogi-poc"
  application             = "pogi-poc"
  solution_stack_name     = "64bit Amazon Linux 2018.03 v2.9.8 running PHP 7.0"
  setting {
    namespace = "aws:ec2:vpc"
    name      = "VPCId"
    value     = "vpc-12345"
  }
  setting {
    namespace = "aws:ec2:vpc"
    name = "ELBScheme"
    value = "internal"
  }
  setting {
    namespace = "aws:ec2:vpc"
    name = "AssociatePublicIpAddress"
    value = "false"
  }
  setting = {
    namespace = "aws:elasticbeanstalk:healthreporting:system"
    name = "ConfigDocument"
    value = data.template_file.hc.rendered
  }
}
```

I also used this [approach](https://github.com/terraform-providers/terraform-provider-aws/issues/150) tried by someone however I'm getting same error message

Comment: Is it related to `"aws:elasticbeanstalk:healthreporting:system`? If you remove this setting, does it work?

Comment: @Marcin - yes it is related to "aws:elasticbeanstalk:healthreporting:system" it works fine after I remove it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have `=` in:

```
  setting = {
    namespace = "aws:elasticbeanstalk:healthreporting:system"
    name = "ConfigDocument"
    value = data.template_file.hc.rendered
  }
```

It should be:

```
  setting {
    namespace = "aws:elasticbeanstalk:healthreporting:system"
    name = "ConfigDocument"
    value = data.template_file.hc.rendered
  }
```

Comment: it worked, its on my fault I didn't saw that "=" 
Thanks,you saved me again today !!

Comment: @Lagot No problem. I also didn't see it at  first :-)